# how do I get rewrite rules working from the apache .htaccess while CSS and javascript files are not rewritten?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

Been through other suggested questions but no luck.
These is my .htaccess rewrite rules, mainly being done for SEO and user-friendliness purposes:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|css|js|scripts/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteRule ^dictionary/(.*) dictionary.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^dict/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I uncomment the rewrite rule so any requests to [www.xyz.com/dictionary](http://www.xyz.com/dictionary) and internally rewritten to [www.xyz.com/dictionary.php](http://www.xyz.com/dictionary.php), with any query string added to it, the entire site stops working.

What I would like is that any request to the folders JS, CSS, images and scripts is not rewritten (so I do not get /dictionary.images/xyz.jpg) and php files included in dictionary.php are not rewritten.

Any request to a anexisting directory is not touched, but if a directory that doesn't exist is rewritten to /index.php

How can I get the rewrite 'fake' directories rewritten please? I have about 5 more  fake directories that I'd like to re-write, and the CSS, JavaScript and images are loaded from he correct paths?

Comment: The code you posted already excludes CSS, JS and images from being rewritten (unless maybe if the URL-path starts `dict`). Is your actual problem that the static resources aren't loading because the browser is requesting them from the wrong URL-path depth? Are you using relative URL-paths to your static resources? If so, see the following question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Comment: Thanks to MrWhite. I now modified the path, as if the file was in a directory, as the file was in site root and had a url to css/abc.css but now I made the path as /css/abc.css and all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite conditions only apply to the very next rule.   When you insert the "dictionary" rule inbetween the `index.php` rule and its rewrite conditions above it, they stop applying to that rule and break your site. You need to add your new rule in *some other place*.

I would suggest adding new lines to emphasize which conditions go with which rules.

Your `dict` and `dictionary` rules need to go near the top so that those paths don't get handled by your [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) (`index.php`)

Try:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^dict/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]

    RewriteRule ^dictionary/(.*) dictionary.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|css|js|scripts/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, The redirection worked perfectly and the URL did not change :)

Comment: 1 more Question, Stephen (or anyone else who can give me diorection).
If URL is ww.xyz.com/dict I get the home page but if I do www.xyz.com/dict/ I get a proper internal URL rewrite. Should I write the rule twice, one with the ending backslash and the other without, or is there some magic regex trick?

Comment: If by "magic regex trick" you mean making the slash and everything that follows it optional by using parenthesis with a `?`:  `RewriteRule ^dict(?:/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+))?$ $1  [L]`

Comment: @AldoCauchiSavona "if I do `www.xyz.com/dict/` I get a proper internal URL rewrite" - do you mean `/dictionary/`? With the above rules, neither a request for `/dict` or `/dict/` would trigger a rewrite (except possibly to the front-controller, ie. `index.php`).

Comment: @MrWhite, With the above rules www.xyz.com/dict/ worked, not www.xyz.com/dict (without the final backslah).

I'm presently converting files to a friendly directory structure. Eventually i'll be working on querystring, i've seen articles/posts where the query string as a directory in the url, but will first get the site running with directories